# invalidate() doesn't recall OnDraw method

Tags: android, ondraw, invalidation

`invalidate()` doesn't recall my `OnDraw()` method. I use `invalidate()` in a setter method in the same class that `OnDraw()` is in.

```
public class PuzzleDraw extends View {

    // defining some variables //

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // codes for painting puzzle //
    }

    public PuzzleDraw(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    // Method for giving cursor X/Y from MainActivity OnTouch() method and using it in OnDraw() method in some part of painting code //

    public void setCursor(int i, int j) {
        this.xx = i;
        this.yy = j;
        invalidate();
    }
```

When I debug my code, everything is good except RECALLING `OnDraw()` when `invalidate()` executes...
in fact, `invalidate()` is doing nothing for me!
What is wrong?
I used `postInvalidate()`, `this.invalidate()`, `this.postInvalidate()` too, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

Calling to `invalidate()` wouldn't execute `onDraw` directly, it only sets the appropriate flag in the `View` class. Your `onDraw` method will be called by framework the next time when view hierarchy is traversed.

Comment: so what can i do? i need my OnDraw() to execute in every executing of OnTouch() event... i need it.

Comment: If you have called `invalidate` your `onDraw` method will be definitely executed as fast as system will be available to draw your view. If you want more control over drawing process you should consider using `SurfaceView`.

Comment: the problem isnt about Fast or Slow!... problem is that my OnDraw() method dont work when invalidate() called. (not "works slow", just dont work)

Comment: problem solved. i was create a sample of my OnDraw class in defining of my puzzle Component, so every OnTouch() execution makes a new object with default construction values. now i access exactly the same component that i create firstly in my puzzle component and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You might be calling setCursor(float, float) method only a single time by calling it from activity but invalidate method have to be called again and again if you wish to call onDraw method internally by the framework itself.

Hope this will work

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Both `postInvalidate()` and `invalidate()` was not invoking the `onDraw()` function as I wanted to update the view in real time when some text typed in the `EditText`. Look at my solution, hopefully this will work for all of you.

1. You will use this custom view somewhere in Activity or Fragment right?
2. In that Activity or Fragment put below code.

   `private PuzzleDraw puzzle; // Define variable of your custom view`
3. Since you will have used that customView (PazzleDraw) in the layout file, which will have some unique id like we do for button listening etc.

   `puzzle = findViewById(R.id.pazzle); // Access the custom view you defined in layout file with id = pazzle`
4. Now here is the main thing, If you want to change custom view based on some event then put the below code in that event listner.

   `pazzle.setVisibility(View.GONE); pazzle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
5. This will now work in real time for you without calling `invalidate()` or `postInvalidate()` functions.

Why this will work? Actually android invoke the `onDraw()` method when the custom view is triggered. For example in the above case we are hiding the custom view and then making it visible so in this case android will invoke the `onDraw()` method. Also is there is some `EditText` on your layout and you focus the input. Then keyboard will open, android will call `onDraw()` on opening of keyboard and also closing of keyboard buttons.
I hope this will work for all of you guys, As I was doing implementing the same thing and it worked for me.